# mirror server for clustering

Tags: mirror, mirror-site

I have three servers worldwide. One in the U.S., one in Asia and one in Europe.
I want to make them mirror servers, so that when a surfer enters the U.S. He will serve in the United States. If a user enters the site from Europe, he will serve in Europe.
Is this possible? If so how do I make it low budget?
Please help me the most urgent issue. Thank you all

Comment: Can you describe the OS and nature what you'll serving with these servers? Websites? Something else?

Comment: Are these servers part of Amazon's EC2 and is your DNS with Route53?  Because if they are, much more specific advice is available about how to direct the traffic to the correct server.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve geographic load balancing with [anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) and then use whatever your OS or application provides for keeping servers or application configuration in sync. If it's Linux, rsync in a cron is an easy way to get started. If you're in Windows, DFS will do the trick.

Of course, there are plenty more complex ways to do this that offer various benefits, but this will gets you pointed in the right direction.